# Crossing sequences

Tags: code-golf, sequence, array

## Crossing Sequences

Given a list of positive integers `A`, call it an *increasing sequence* if each element is greater than or equal to the previous one; and call it a *decreasing sequence* if each element is less than or equal to the previous one.

Some increasing sequences:

```
[1,2,4,7]
[3,4,4,5]
[2,2,2]
[]
```

Some decreasing sequences:

```
[7,4,2,1]
[5,4,4,3]
[2,2,2]
[]
```

A *crossing sequence* is a list that can be decomposed into two disjoint subsequences, one an increasing sequence and the other a decreasing sequence.

For example, the list:

```
[3,5,2,4,1]
```

is a crossing sequence, since it can be decomposed into:

```
[3,    4  ]
[  5,2,  1]
```

where `[3,4]` is the increasing subsequence and `[5,2,1]` is the decreasing subsequence. We'll call such a pair of (increasing,decreasing) subsequences a *decomposition* of the crossing sequence.

The list:

```
[4,5,2,1,3]
```

is not a crossing sequence; there is no way to decompose it into an increasing and decreasing subsequence.

Your task is to write a program/function taking as input a list of positive integers; and if it is a crossing sequence, return the two lists in one of its decompositions; or some consistent "falsey" value if the list is not a crossing sequence.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf); shortest program/function in each language is the winner.

### Rules:

- Input is flexible.
- The usual loopholes are forbidden.
- If there are multiple valid ways to decompose the input, you may output one or all of them.
- Output formatting for the decomposition is flexible; but it must be unambiguous regarding the distinction between the two subsequences.
- You may use any consistent output value to indicate that the input is not a crossing sequence; so long as it is unambiguous compared to the output for any crossing sequence. You should specify the falsey value in your answer.

### Test Cases:

Using `False` to indicate non-crossing sequences:

```
[3, 5, 2, 4, 1] => [3, 4], [5, 2, 1]
[3, 5, 2, 4, 4, 1, 1] => [3, 4, 4], [5, 2, 1, 1]

[7, 9, 8, 8, 6, 11] => [7, 8, 8, 11], [9, 6]
[7, 9, 8, 8, 6, 11] => [7, 9, 11], [8, 8, 6] # also valid
[7, 9, 8, 8, 6, 11] => [7, 8, 11], [9, 8, 6] # also valid

[7, 8, 9, 10, 20, 30] => [7, 8, 9, 20, 30], [10]
[7, 8, 9, 10, 20, 30] => [8, 9, 10, 20, 30], [7] # this is also valid

[5, 5, 5] => [5, 5, 5], []

[4, 5, 2, 1, 3] => False
[3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 2, 4] => False
```

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/60675/one-goes-up-the-other-comes-down). Only two differences I see is that the other challenge should be run in polynomial time in the length of the input, and allows for a truthy value instead of the two subsequences (returning the subsequences themselves will receive a 20% bonus though). Still sounds like a dupe to me, but I won't hammer it.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen time restriction is probably enough on its own not to make this a dupe.

Comment: @NickKennedy Possibly yeah, which is why I refrained from hammering it. :)

Comment: Suggested test case: `[3, 5, 2, 4, 4, 1, 1]`. The current test cases let you get away with `>=` / `<`, when it should really be `>=` / `<=`.

Comment: _You should specify the **falsey** value in your answer_ -> may this value be truthy, as long as it's consistent and cannot be interpreted as a solution?

Comment: @Arnauld : Yes, it can be any value ("falsey" is just to say: it is false that the input is a crossing sequence).

Answer (score 1):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 17 bytes

```
;Ṣzpᵐz{ℕˢ}ᵐ≤₁ʰ≥₁ᵗ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRuX/2obcOjpuaaRx3LldISc4pT9ZRqH@7qrH24dcJ/64c7F1UVAFlV1Y9app5eBBJ81LnkUVPjqQ2POpcC6Ydbp///H60QbayjYKqjYKSjYKKjYBirE22uo2Cpo2ABRmZAIaiYBVjY0ACoFIiNDYCipmCdpkCWCcwMQ6AUkG8MNg1CQg2PVYgFAA)

There's probably considerable room to golf this.

Comment: You've already answered this challenge before [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/181253/52210), where you did it in 16 bytes. ;)

Comment: I couldn't shake the feeling that there was something similar I'd done, but for some reason my mind decided it had to have been [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/180975/85334) instead

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>15</s> <s>14</s> 13 bytes

```
2.Œ.ΔćRšεü@}W
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##ASwA0/9vc2FiaWX//zIuxZIuzpTEh1LFoc61w7xAfVf//1szLCA1LCAyLCA0LCAxXQ) or [validate all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W/m5mKvpKCra6egZP/fSO/oJL1zU460Bx1deG7r4T0OteH/a3X@RxvrKJjqKBjpKJjoKBjGckWb6yhY6ihYgJEZUAgqZgEWNjQAKgViYwOgqClYpymQZQIzwxAoBeQbg02DkFDDYwE).

Explanation:

```
2.Œ                    # all partitions of the input in 2 subsequences
   .Δ                  # find the first partition such that the following gives 1
     ćRš               # reverse the first subsequence
        ε  }           # map each subsequence to
         ü@            # pairwise greater-than
            W          # minimum (1 if all 1s, 0 otherwise)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 bytes

```
ŒPżṚ$ṢNÞƭ€ƑƇ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opICjex7unKXycOciv8Pzjq191LTm2MRj7f8Ptx@d9HDnjP//o811FCx1FCzAyExHwdAwFgA)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>110 105</s>  104 bytes

Returns either `[[decreasing], [increasing]]` or \$1\$ if there's no solution.

```javascript
f=(a,n,b=[[],[]])=>a.some((v,i)=>[...x=b[i=n>>i&1]].pop()*(x.push(v),i-=!i)>v*i)?n>>a.length||f(a,-~n):b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY/BTsMwEETvfIW5ELvaWA1paKnk8BkcjA9OSZqtgh0RJ@qh4tfDNhSpiIBkW1rP08zswQ62271jG2LnX8txrBS34KBQWhvQxgiVW9n5t5LzAZAmLaU8qkKjcnmOd4kxsvUtFwt@lG3f1XwQgLG6RZEPCxRPRFnZlG4f6tOpIvP4w4ltMe6863xTysbvefSMoWaW0Ucf0LttJG6u9YrrFFgG7B7YClhixC99DewR2GY6D4T8wWwmLFmSFd10OUNlU1I2o1x3ONe4NPmBRS/uvIzvw//7rL69yCWdzyLk672EEjV@Ag)

### How?

We try all values of a bitmask \$n\$ between \$0\$ and \$2^L\$, where \$L\$ is the length of the input array.

At each iteration, we split the original array into two subsequences \$b[0]\$ (decreasing) and \$b[1]\$ (increasing), using each bit \$i\$ of \$n\$ to know where each value goes.

When a new value is added to a subsequence, we simultaneously make sure that it's not invalid by comparing it with the last value, popped from a copy of the subsequence. The direction of the inequality is always the same, but the operands are multiplied by either \$1\$ (if \$i=1\$) or \$-1\$ (if \$i=0\$):

```javascript
[...x = b[i = n >> i & 1]].pop() * (x.push(v), i -= !i) > v * i
```

We stop and return \$b\$ as soon as all values are passing, i.e. `some()` is falsy.

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, 84 bytes

```
(([],[])#)
(d,i)#(a:b)=(#b)=<<[(d++[a],i)|all(a<=)d]++[(d,i++[a])|all(a>=)i]
p#_=[p]
```

Returns a list of all valid `(decreasing,increasing)` pairs or the empty list if there's no such pair.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY65DsIwEER7f8UKU9jKIoX7UMwX0FGaFTKYQIQJVhI6vh1jrgIodop5M5o9mPq4cy7kahWE0ISaJJdMWCwkF2a2kUrwKFmmhU0SbSiCq3FOmExJS9F6ZJ/k7c@VLIh5vlbaUziZogQF9swAfFWUDbQhB91HGCL0EAYIXfpmI4TRjzVGmCBMYzaNrXj9lNgjcmmWTbUoodVi343BZ6Abw/Q3HvFL319QuG1zZ/Z16Gy9vwM)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>109</s> 107 bytes

```python
def f(l,i=[],d=[]):
 if l:s,*r=l;i and s<i[-1]or f(r,i+[s],d);d and s>d[-1]or f(r,i,d+[s])
 else:print(i,d)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZDLDsIgEEX3/YqJq6JjYm3ro1r3rvwAQkwjEEkabAou/Po6fVhrIoEJnDtzGahe/v6wcdNIpUGHJZqcC5QUWBaA0VBmDud1Xh4MFFaCOxq@jMSjpuQazYI7ymYH2YsnORVRtjILQJVOZVVtrA8JssYr56@3wikHOXAeI6QIa4QEIRIIP6BlA94i7BF23dwQ@8Bdx6MVldCKVy1OO4u03SYfN/KJB3tifRzuESIINPU9dgbGfg@OvoJG/4LZ2VZPn81wlNlUvTx9J/dQh3@zWPMG)

The function prints all possible decompositions to the standard output. If there are no possible decompositions, nothing is printed.

Thanks to @Sriotchilism O'Zaic for improvement suggestions.

Comment: Welcome to the site.  I suggest doing `s<i[-1]` rather than `i[-1]>s ` and similar with `d[-1]<s `, both save a byte.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've updated the answer. Is there any copy-pastable template here for publishing answers?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean?  TIO has a template that you seem to already be using.

Comment: I only generated a link on TIO and added the link to my post. I did not use any template there. Where is it?

Comment: @Joel - At the top of the TIO page there's an icon that looks like some chain links. Click that, and then you get a page of options. One of them is 'Code Golf Submission'. That will put into your copy buffer the formatted stuff you want! Welcome also, and nice solution!

Comment: @Chas Brown Oh, I see. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 147 bytes

```python
def f(a):
 for i in range(2**len(a)):
	x=[];y=[]
	for c in a:[x,y][i&1]+=[c];i/=2
	if x==sorted(x)and y[::-1]==sorted(y[::-1]):return x,y
 return 0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY5BCsMgEEXX8RSzKklqaWOSjcGTiAtJtBWKCdaCnt5OSshmmHn/Mfwtx9fqWSmLsWBr3XACdg3gwHkI2j9Nzdr2bTxGmFVJSDVlHKTatXnXNJeJZiXdpVNXIWc1ubtgpHIWkhCfNUSz1KnRfoEsOb916qTH3fBg4jd4wD8Ejv1RtuB8xFaypyNldKBokhMOf9jRHmH5AQ)